# cancel one of the parallel task in activiti BPM

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I have an activiti bpmn2 subprocess that contains two parallel tasks. I want to continue the process when any one of the parallel tasks completes. I joined the parallel tasks using an exclusive gateway, but it waits for both the tasks to be complete.

How do I cancel one user task on completion of another user task?

Comment: you may design parallel/sequential tasks as separate subprocesses - it is more flexible and reliable.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov How do we cancel the subprocess on completion of another subprocess? Becoz on completion of any one of the parallel task, I have to continue processing in main process.

Comment: That is more about your preferences to design BPM. One of many options: `Main process` -> `Task Manager subprocess` -> `Task subprocess`.  `Task Manager` has two parallel activities: `Wait termination event` and `Launch Task subprocess`. `Task subprocess` sends `Termination event` to `Task Manager`  upon completion, `Task Manager` terminates remaining `Task subprocess`es